# How would I sort data accordence month and year using django queryset and serializer

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django serializers. I have model Order and I want to have some kind of response that is shown below in JSON format from Order Model using **serializer** (Django REST framework).

Example:
Order Model

```
class Order(models.Model):
    shop = models.ForeignKey(Shop, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Required Response

```
{
    "order_by_month_year":[
        {
            "month": "January 2021",
            "order_list":
            [
                {
                "id":12,
                },
                {
                "id":23
                },
                {
                "id":34
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "month": "Febuary 2021",
            "order_list":
            [
                {
                "id":123
                },
                {
                "id":233
                },
                {
                "id":334
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: is `id` field,  `pk` value of `Order` model itself?

Comment: Yes, It is ```id``` or ```pk``` that is auto-generated by Django @JyothiS.